# Is there a way to dynamically change a comparison operator?

Tags: c++, boolean, operator-keyword, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

I'm creating an AI Director and need a way to change when the AI needs to pressure the player and when they need to move away. I've got a TArray of Objects and am checking the distance from the player. I'd like to either get the largest distance or the smallest distance.

I know this doesn't work:

```
operator comparer = PlayerTensionLevel > BackstageThreshold ? > : <;
```

Both of the variables used in the one line Bool are floats. I'm hoping that the comparer can be used in a situation like:

```
if(DistanceSquared(objectA, objectB) comparer _currentThresholdDistance){
    _currentObject = objectA;
    _currentThresholdDistance = DistanceSquared(objectA, objectB);
}
```

Comment: `#define comparer(a,b) ((PlayerTensionLevel > BackstageThreshold) ? (a>b) : (a<b))` would let you `if(comparer(DistanceSquared(objectA, objectB),_currentThresholdDistance))` but getting something infix will be hard.

Comment: Use `std::function`, and initialize it with either `std::less` or `std::greater`?

Comment: Do not use the macro method. What you need is a strategy pattern, so either you have two compare objects with the same interface that you can switch. Or as sam says you have a way to switch between two functions at runtime.

Comment: Please do not use both UE5 and UE4 tags.

Answer (score 2):

You can **compute** with `bool`!  If you aren’t concerned with differing behavior for ties, you can just write

```
if((DistanceSquared(objectA, objectB) > _currentThresholdDistance) ==
   (PlayerTensionLevel > BackstageThreshold)) …
```

(Technically, the extra parentheses here are unnecessary, but it’s probably not reasonable to expect the reader to know that relational operators have higher precedence than equality operators.)

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in @SamVarshavchik's comment above,
You can use [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and assign it to either [`std::less`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less) or [`std::greater`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater) based on `PlayerTensionLevel` and `BackstageThreshold`.

After you determine the comparator you can use it against the current values of `_currentThresholdDistance` and the the squared distance between the objects (here I just used `dist2` to represent it).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

std::function<bool(float a, float b)>
     GetComp(float PlayerTensionLevel, float BackstageThreshold)
{
    if (PlayerTensionLevel > BackstageThreshold) {
        return std::less<float>{};
    }
    return std::greater<float>{};
}

int main() {
    float _currentThresholdDistance = 1;
    float dist2 = 2;

    float PlayerTensionLevel = 100;
    float BackstageThreshold;

    BackstageThreshold = 101;
    std::cout << GetComp(PlayerTensionLevel, BackstageThreshold)
                        (dist2, _currentThresholdDistance) << std::endl;

    BackstageThreshold = 99;
    std::cout << GetComp(PlayerTensionLevel, BackstageThreshold)
                        (dist2, _currentThresholdDistance) << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
1
0
```

Comment: To add to this, Unreal has its own `TLess<T>` and `TGreater<T>` templated predicates, which is advised to use when writing Unreal specific code.

Comment: @goose_lake my solution can be easily adapted to use `TLess<T>` etc. if needed - just replace `std::less` etc. with it in `GetComp` .